# Elasticsearch issue on a scale level

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to sync the user's followers in the index userfollower nested array as SOCIAL_CONTACT.

There are multiple users having more than 20K followers while syncing followers.

Multiple times it gets stuck while followers sync.

**Note**: We have multiple users who have more than 1M followers.

What should be the suitable setting and mapping for such index?

Currently, we are getting the issue which is mentioned below:

***Error::***

**Type:**
unavailable_shards_exception

**Reason:**

```
[userfollower][2] [1] shardIt, 
[0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], 
request: indices:data/write/update
```

**Error Code:**
503

**Setting:**

```
{"userfollower":{"settings":{"index":{"mapping":{"nested_objects":{"limit":"2000000"}},"number_of_shards":"5","blocks":{"read_only_allow_delete":"false","write":"false"},"provided_name":"userfollower","creation_date":"1622652295522","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"xyz","version":{"created":"7100299"}}}}}
```

**Mapping:**

```
{"userfollower":{"mappings":{"dynamic":"strict","properties":{"EMAIL":{"type":"text"},"FIRSTNAME":{"type":"text"},"MOBILE_NUMBER":{"type":"long"},"NOT_VISIBLE_IDS":{"type":"text"},"SOCIAL_CONTACT":{"type":"nested","include_in_parent":true,"properties":{"DEGREE":{"type":"long"},"FOLLOWER":{"type":"long"}}},"TOTAL_FOLLOWER":{"type":"long"},"USERID":{"type":"long"},"USERNAME":{"type":"text"},"USER_STRING_UNIQUE_ID":{"type":"text"}}}}}
```

**Current Index Details:**

```
Index Name: userfollower
Health: Red
Status: Open
Doc Count: 53389111
Size: 4.2gb
ES Version: 7.10
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanking you in advance.

Comment: how many shards is unassigned? use this  api : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/cluster-allocation-explain.html . and share more data.

Comment: and this setting: :{"nested_objects":{"limit":"2000000"}} ???? you would have out of memory in future. dont use nested field. put all followers in separate document and use a unique field for relating them together like following username. I think cassandra is more suitable for you job.